# Как узнать Циркулирующее Предложение криптовалюты?

Tags: криптовалюта

https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/ В таблице есть столбец Circulating Supply. Мене нужно знать как или где coinmarketcap берет эти значения.

Я не нашел этих данных в документацыи Binance API  https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Я исследовал много статтей о том что такое Circulating Supply и похоже что эти данные должны предоставлять API бирж. Но все биржы которые я исследовал не предоставляють таких данных.

Если сравнить https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/ и https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/overview/USD можно увидеть что Circulating Supply имеют почти одинаковые значения. Как эти сайты вычисляют эти значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circulating supply - это общий объем монет/токенов. Биржи не имеют никакого отношения к ним.

Если монета майнится - вам нужно быть подключенным к сети, что бы знать, сколько всего монет намайнено.

Если "монета" не майнится, вам нужно уже смотреть детали, как она работает, и как узнать общее количество монет.

Если "монета" это токен, выпущенный на другой криптовалюте, вы должны посмотреть, сколько всего этих токенов было выпущено.

Comment: Спасибо @Zergatul.

https://coinmarketcap.com/faq/ здесь также указано как вычислить **Market Cap**

`Market Cap = Price X Circulating Supply`

Но я не нашел ничего про **Circulating Supply** в api binance, и не только в binance.

Или я чтото очевидное не понимаю, или это значение очень тяжело вычислить, либо я вообще не туда копаю. Уже несколько дней не могу понять.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные пути решения. Что еще можно почитать или к кому обратится?

Comment: @bo9enr я невнимательно прочитал, ответил совсем не то, я исправил полностью ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но разве это не **Total Supply**?

Comment: @bo9enr нет, Total Supply это что-то другое. Это значение не оторабжается для криптовалют, которые майнятся. В них есть только Max Supply - это сколько всего монет может быть добыто. Больше этого значение правила сети не позволяют сделать.

Comment: Возможно Total Supply - это Circulating Supply + замороженные токены, которые в данный момент нельзя использовать.